# Periodic Django Logs in Terminal

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and this question may seem to be easy. In the terminal where "python manage.py runserver" is executed, the following logs periodically appear.

```
[30/Sep/2015 02:36:02] "GET /messages/check/?_=1443574208652 HTTP/1.1" 200 1
[30/Sep/2015 02:36:08] "GET /notifications/check/?_=1443574208653 HTTP/1.1" 200 1
[30/Sep/2015 02:36:08] "GET /feeds/update/?first_feed=13&last_feed=6&feed_source=all&_=1443574208655 HTTP/1.1" 200 173
[30/Sep/2015 02:36:08] "GET /feeds/check/?last_feed=13&feed_source=all&_=1443574208654 HTTP/1.1" 200 1
[30/Sep/2015 02:36:39] "GET /notifications/check/?_=1443574208656 HTTP/1.1" 200 1
[30/Sep/2015 02:36:39] "GET /feeds/check/?last_feed=13&feed_source=all&_=1443574208658 HTTP/1.1" 200 1
[30/Sep/2015 02:36:39] "GET /feeds/update/?first_feed=13&last_feed=6&feed_source=all&_=1443574208657 HTTP/1.1" 200 173
[30/Sep/2015 02:37:03] "GET /messages/check/?_=1443574208659 HTTP/1.1" 200 1
```

My Django virtual environment is as follows:

```
bleach==1.4
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.6.5
gunicorn==19.3.0
html5lib==0.9999999
Markdown==2.4.1
Pillow==2.4.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
python-decouple==2.2
six==1.9.0
South==0.8.4
static3==0.6.1
Unipath==1.0
```

Questions are:

1. Why does the logs periodically appear? I guess there is a background task running.But Celery package is not used here.
2. How to configure the logs, for example, displaying one more logs such as:

   /followers/check/?_=9896886900907 HTTP/1.1
3. What do "?_" and the long string of numbers stand for? I can understand the "?first_feed=13" means the querying parameter in Django request object.

   GET /notifications/check/?_=1443574208656

Answer (score 0):

When Django is run in development mode (with `runserver`) it prints a line for all HTTP requests received to the console.

All of them are coming from the outside, browsers, feed readers...
The parameters you are wondering about are GET query parameters. The `?` is the delimiter so, `_` is the key of the argument.

In development mode the logging is defined by default. If you want to have logging on your production system or more logging, read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/ .

Comment: Thanks. I am not initiating any HTTP requests in the browser, but the terminal console still prints and ONLY prints those logs periodically. Those logs are related to some views in the modules such as feed, messages.